# Pass multiple objects to onRetainNonConfigurationInstance

Tags: android, android-orientation

In my app I have to check user location and then connect to server to find out what is the nearest city. It means I have two expensive objects, that I would like to retain on configuration change. One is the task which find out the location, and the other is AsyncTask to retrieve data from server. Now what should I do, to retain both?

My approach is to create a static class in my Activity like this:

```
static class NonConfigurationObject{

    MyLocation myLocationObject;
    AsyncTask myAsyncTask;

}
```

Then when these two objects are created I pass them to this NonConfigurationObject and retain this object and then find out if MyLocation and AsyncTask are there and if there is no need to create them.

Is this a good approach? Because it seems good to me, but I didn't see it done this way anywhere.

EDIT: So this approach seems to be ok. But if you have another way of doing it, please share it.

Comment: I also finding some way to pass multiple object, can you tell more how did you accomplished this.

Comment: This is not the right way to do it anymore. `onRetainNonCOnfigurationInstance` is deprecated now: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance().

Comment: So how could be this done.

Comment: There's really lots of examples out there. You can start with "Related" questions section on the right side. Generally the best way would be to use `Fragments` and `setRetainInstance()`. But it really depends on what you need.

Comment: Okay thnks for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an acceptable approach as long as you use a static class to avoid leaking memory.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. It's ACCEPTABLE, you say. So is there any better, more optimized, simplier, whatever approach?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way. It is light weight, simple and fast. I say acceptable because I don't like saying there is only one way to do something :)